# Wagtail(Django) ModelAdmin Button view action

Tags: python, django, wagtail

i want to put a button into wagtail admin for inspect in view mode, by default edit and delete are shown, but i don't know what need to do for call a view that contain only view of a model

[image: wagtail admin]

here is my code:

products.models.py

```
class CamisaOrder(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('PAYMENTVERFICATION','Verificacion Forma Pago'), ('PROCESSINGORDER','Procesando Orden'), 
        ('MAKING','Elaboracion'),
        ('PROCESSINGSHIPING','Preparando Envio'),
        ('SHIPPED','Enviado'),
        ('DELIVERED','Recibido'),
        ('CANCELED','Cancelado'),
        ('RETURNED','Retornado'),
        )   
    camisa = models.ForeignKey('CamisetaProduct',related_name='+', on_delete= models.PROTECT)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="PROCESSINGORDER")

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('camisa'),
        FieldPanel('cantidad'),
        FieldPanel('status')
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Camisa Orden"
        verbose_name_plural="Camisas Ordenes"
```

wagtail_hooks.py

```
class ProductButtonHelper(ButtonHelper):

 
    view_button_classnames = ['button-small', 'icon', 'icon-site'] 

    def view_button(self, obj):
        # Define a label for our button
        text = 'View {}'.format(self.verbose_name)
        logging.debug(obj)
        return {
            'url': #url here for inspect model#
            'label': text,
            'classname': self.finalise_classname(self.view_button_classnames),
            'title': text,
        }

    def get_buttons_for_obj(self, obj, exclude=None, classnames_add=None, classnames_exclude=None):
        btns = super().get_buttons_for_obj(obj, exclude, classnames_add, classnames_exclude)
        if 'view' not in (exclude or []):
            btns.append(
                self.view_button(obj)
            )
        return btns



class CamisetaOrderAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = CamisaOrder
    button_helper_class = ProductButtonHelper  
    menu_label = 'Pedidos y Ordenes'
    menu_icon = 'mail'
    menu_order = 200
    add_to_settings_menu =  False
    exclude_from_explorer =  False
    list_display = ('camisa', 'cantidad', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status',)
    search_fields = ( 'status',)


modeladmin_register(CamisetaOrderAdmin)
```

how i can achieve this approach?

i need to do a custom view and insert into wagtail admin model if is this, how can i do that ? can i make a model form like popup showing custom actions for models? something like change his state or some value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

i find a solution,  adding `inspect_view_enabled` on ModelAdmin class

```
class CamisetaOrderAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = CamisaOrder
   # button_helper_class = ProductButtonHelper  # ProductButtonHelper
   # url_helper_class = CustomPageAdminURLHelper
    menu_label = 'Pedidos y Ordenes'
    menu_icon = 'mail'
    menu_order = 200
    add_to_settings_menu =  False
    exclude_from_explorer =  False
    list_display = ('camisa', 'cantidad', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status',)
    search_fields = ( 'status',)
    inspect_view_enabled=True
    inspect_view_fields = ('camisa', 'cantidad', 'status')
```

reference: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/inspectview.html